# How to add com reference in Rider

Tags: c#, visual-studio, reference, com, rider

In Visual Studio, we can "Add as COM model" to add a link in our project in the solution. But how you can do it in Rider?
I see only add reference to project.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Rider does not add references (both to framework assemblies and com components) for .net core projects. Which target framework does your project target? Probably netcoreapp.

Comment: for .net 4.8 i can not do it too

Comment: that is interesting. I can add com references under Windows to a .net core project which targets full framework (net48 for example)

Comment: on rider or visual studio, how can i do it @xtmq

Comment: Could you share your project file? I will try to reproduce the issue. I just take a simple net48 console app and invoke `add reference` dialog